# Image tag closing

Tags: html

How to close image tag in HTML?

```
<img src="#"></img>
```

or

```
<img src="#" />
```

or

```
 <img src="#">
```

Comment: What version of HTML are you after?

Comment: 2nd and 3rd is correct.it if wont close also it working

Comment: What is version? I use new HTML.

Comment: There is HTML 5 as the newest but HTML 4 is still quite prevalent.

Comment: HTML6? I don't believe such a thing exists...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per this HTML5 standard: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element

> Start tags consist of the following parts, in exactly the following
> order:
>
> 1. A "<" character.
> 2. The element’s tag name.
> 3. Optionally, one or more attributes, each of which must be preceded by one or more space characters.
> 4. Optionally, one or more space characters.
> 5. Optionally, a "/" character, which may be present only if the element is a void element.
> 6. A ">" character.

The `img` is a *void* element and hence the part #5 would apply with a caveat that "*a '/' character, which **may** be present...*"

```
<img id="..." src="..." />
```

And so, you ***may*** omit the part #5 i.e. the closing "/", and hence this is also valid:

```
<img id="..." src="..." >
```

Further down the spec says:

> Void elements only have a start tag; end tags must not be specified
> for void elements.

So, no end tag is required.

Answer (score 3):

**in xhtml:**

```
<img src="#" alt="some explaining" />
```

the closing / is for backwards compatibility

**in html5**

```
<img src="#" alt="some explaining">
```

no need anymore to close the `<img>` tag, (*the browser knows that it is self-closing*)

more info here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element (thanks to Chris)

Comment: Might be nice to include spec reference. The HTML 5 one is http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element. Also the xhtml is not for backwards compatibility, it is so that it is valid XML markup.

Comment: @Chris: thanks
user: always do some alt attribute, it is for when the image can not be loaded, or screen-readers, then the alt will be visible

Answer (score 1):

[HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#didx-empty_element) and earlier:

```
<img> <!-- end tag forbidden -->
```

[XHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.6)

```
<img/> <!-- self closing tag syntax -->
<img></img>
```

[HTML Compatible XHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_2)

```
<img /> <!-- self closing tag syntax with a space -->
```

[HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element)

```
<img> <!-- end tag forbidden -->
<img /> <!-- end tag forbidden but a / allowed for people addicted to XML -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<img src="#" />
```

An image tag can't have any content, but you do need to close it in HTML4. In HTML5 this is not required any more.

So then this is also allowed:

```
<img src="#">
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an empty element so you can close the start tag itself like this

```
<img src="YOUR_FILE"/>
```

or 
you can even not closing it like this

```
<img src="YOUR_FILE">
```