# HTML/CSS - Automatically set height width from background image?

Tags: html, css

Longshot... I don't think this is possible but I've been shocked before!

I anchor tags, all of which have background images, all 300px wide but their heights all vary.  Is there anyway to set these without actually having to type out the height?  Sort of setting it to the bg url's dimensions?

Thanks!

I don't think people understand - My fault for rushing the question.

Here's code as an example:

```
#ex-1 {width: 300px; height: 410px; background: url('/image-1.jpg');}
#ex-2 {width: 300px; height: 420px; background: url('/image-2.jpg');}
#ex-3 {width: 300px; height: 430px; background: url('/image-3.jpg');}
#ex-4 {width: 300px; height: 440px; background: url('/image-3.jpg');}

<a href="#" id="ex-1"></a>
<a href="#" id="ex-2"></a>
<a href="#" id="ex-3"></a>
<a href="#" id="ex-4"></a>
```

I'd like to NOT set the height, and it set automatically using CSS only.  I don't want to use image tags.

I wasn't sure if this was possible, I assume not.

Thanks

Comment: Did you consider using in your CSS the tag image for apply once and for all a single height for all future images ? If no, you can do this by typing in your CSS file : `img { height : 100px; }`.

Comment: Each image has a slightly different height - 433px, 404px, 420px etc... So I can't set them that way.  I'm using CSS to set the images as background images.Usually it'd look like #example {width: 300px; height: 500px; background: url('image.jpg');}  <a href="#" id="example"></a>  I was just trying to see if there was any way of automatically setting the height in CSS without having to do it so many times manually

Comment: this can be achieved using Pure CSS and `img` tags instead of background image, if you want to use background image: consider using JavaScript to set the height dynamically

Answer (score 3):

A simple way of doing this is to add an image  like this and then make it hidden i used `visibility:hidden` http://jsfiddle.net/gztpsfkw/1/

i just saw that you don't want to use `<img>` tags but as for here the image is being hidden and it takes up the space.

```
 <a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/301" />aa</a>
```

And apply the css

```
a{
display:block;
background-image:url('http://placekitten.com/300/301');
width:100px;
height:auto;
}

img{
visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: I like `visibility: hidden;` more than `opacity:0;` , but UV for the good answer

Comment: img elements do not have a closing slash.

Comment: @Rob see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860492/how-to-close-img-tag-properly you can also try deleting the tag in jsfiddle then the `</a>` will turn up red

Comment: @Akshay Yes. You can do that, and it's valid, but it's ignored by browsers, unnecessary and does nothing but take up space. It's not in the spec that it should be used. So it's pointless.

Comment: @Rob okay got it i usually do it in fiddles because i hate it when my code shows red

Comment: @Akshay don't forget to edit the CSS code in the answer as well (you fixed only the JsFiddle)

Comment: @Akshay I'm still seeing `opacity:0;` in the answer code.

Comment: @Rob: the spec says that closing slash is optional. That does not mean that you have to 'necessarily' omit that. It just means you 'may' wish to omit it.

Comment: @abhitalks The spec says nothing about putting it on img tags except under definition of void elements which 'may' have it. However, it also says the slash is ignored and does nothing. So it has no purpose, is meaningless and pointless. Also this: http://tiffanybbrown.com/2011/03/23/html5-does-not-allow-self-closing-tags/

Comment: @abhitalks i didn't do it, it was edited by someone else, and i edited after it to change something so his name is not displayed

Comment: @Rob: img "is" a void element. and as long as the specs are not violated, such objections are just pedantic.

Comment: @Rob: what you are quoting is not the spec. See this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23739417/1355315 and the official spec here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element

Comment: @abhitalks Yes, it's a void element which is an exception to the main rule. Nowhere is the img tag specifically shown to need or use the closing slash. That the closing slash is optional does not make it any more useful than before and just as useless.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a `visibility: hidden` way:

```
<a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/200/" /></a>
```

**CSS**

```
a {background: url("http://lorempixel.com/100/200/") center center no-repeat; width: 100px;}
a img {visibility: hidden;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/vhjxfgtw/

---

**JavaScript Solution**

#### Procedure

To set the `height`, dynamically, you need to use JavaScript. So, you can get the computed value by adding a `<img />` tag and computing the value by setting the `src`. The pseudo code would have been like this:

1. Get the computed value of `background-image`.
2. Attach it to a new `<img />` element in the DOM.
3. Get the `height` of the new `<img />` element.
4. Set the `height` of the fake background `<div>`.

#### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    bg = $(".bg").css("background-image");
    $("body").append('<img id="faux" src="' + bg.substring(4, bg.length-1) + '" />');
    height = $("#faux").outerHeight();
    $("#faux").remove();
    $(".bg").height(height);
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/rcL3xj0x/

If you don't want to use inline CSS, you can use this:

```
$("style").append('.bg {height: ' + height + 'px}');
```

Comment: a) he does not want to use the `<img>` tag b) he wants a CSS-only solution

Comment: @Wavemaster Oops. Didn't look at it! `:)`

Comment: img tags do not have a closing slash.

Comment: @Rob Please check how to close the the empty tags. http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201005/void_empty_elements_and_self-closing_start_tags_in_html/

Comment: @PraveenKumar Please read the spec on how to close img tags. This is HTML, not XHTML.

Comment: @Rob Please provide the link, but I am keeping XHTML in mind.

Comment: @PraveenKumar If you are writing HTML markup, why are using XHTML syntax? I am surprised I am being asked to supply a link to the spec but, notice, no closing slash: http://developers.whatwg.org/edits.html#the-img-element

Comment: Okay, let's make it clear. I am speaking XHTML, and you are talking HTML! `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Then you are off topic because the question deals with HTML.

Comment: @Rob Yes. And no one will explicitly tag something with `XHTML`! `:)` Let's stop the discussion about this, and I would love to use XHTML, because it is good for devs and machines! `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar This topic is not for you to decide what should be used. However, my point is that I too often see this notion that people think elements such as img have a closing slash and I have the need to quash this misleading thought.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to make the background images fill all the space available then use `background-size: cover`

Comment: I think the OP wants a way for the `<a>` tags's dimensions to adapt to their background images, without using `<img>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
function setBackgroundImage(element, src) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        element.style.height = img.height+'px';
        element.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+img.src+')';
    }
    img.src = src;  
}
```

Or, if you need to scale the images for the width:

```
function setImage(element, src) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        var sizeRatio = element.offsetWidth / img.width;
        element.style.height = (sizeRatio * img.height)+'px';
        element.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+img.src+')';
        element.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
    }
    img.src = src;  
}
```

Comment: the OP is looking for a Pure CSS solution.

Comment: Ah, in that case I feel pretty confident that this is not currently possible without using image tags.

Answer (score 0):

**Side Note:** The `<a>` tag is not a block level element. In order for the `<a>` to have a height and a width you need to make it a block level element to show the background image.

You would use: `display: block`

***Now for your question***... In order to get the background image, with out having to manual type it in you can use a little jQUery to make your life a lot easier. I have modified your CSS and HTML a little bit to accomodate the jQuery.

**[CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNbjXN)**

```
#links { overflow: hidden; }
#links a { display: block; float: left; width: 300px; height: 200px; 
    /* generic height set in case there is no background image */ }
#ex-1 {  background: url('http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png');}
#ex-2 {  background: url('http://www.bing.com/s/a/hpc12.png');}
#ex-3 {  background: url('http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png');}
#ex-4 {  background: url('http://www.bing.com/s/a/hpc12.png');}


<div id="links">
    <a href="#" id="ex-1"></a>
    <a href="#" id="ex-2"></a>
    <a href="#" id="ex-3"></a>
    <a href="#" id="ex-4"></a>
</div>
```

Here is the jquery. It will loop through all your images and set the height according to your background image

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#links a').each(function(){
        var temp = $(this).css('background-image');
        temp = temp.replace('url("', '').replace('")', '');    

        var newImg = new Image();  
        newImg.src = temp;  

        imageHeight = newImg.height;
        imageWidth = newImg.width;  

        $(this).css('height', imageHeight);    
    });
});
```